# Is there a way to load an excel file in openpyxl ignoring the data type?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have an excel file that has the value 20220831 on cell C2, and the cell format is set as date.

When I try to load the file with openpyxl I get this warning:

```
C:\Users\joaquim.MASCARELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\_reader.py:211: UserWarning: Cell C2 is marked as a date but the serial value 20220831 is outside the limits for dates. The cell will be treated as an error.
  warn(msg)
```

And trying to get the cell value results in "#VALUE!":

```py
wb = xl.load_workbook(file)
sheet = wb["Sheet1"]
print(sheet["C2"].value)

>>#VALUE!
```

I would like to get the integer value "20220831".

Is there any parameter that I can pass in order to ignore the type mark and simply return the value that is stored in the xml?

Comment: is the correct datatype a date? I think ```.text``` gets the string representation of a value in excel, but it's probably worth trying

Comment: The correct datatime is not date. The Cell object doesn't have a text atribute.

Comment: It looks like `#VALUE!` is the value in the cell.

Comment: Check [here](https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/issues/1670). Looks like it was a bug and fixed by Charlie Clark an year back. Probably upgrade to latest version of openpyxl

Comment: My openpyxl version is 3.0.10 (the last version, in theory).

Answer (score 0):

a trick way, just delete this row

```
value = "#VALUE!"
```

in C:\Users\joaquim.MASCARELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet_reader.py

```
                    except (OverflowError, ValueError):
                        msg = f"""Cell {coordinate} is marked as a date but the serial value {value} is outside the limits for dates. The cell will be treated as an error."""
                        warn(msg)
                        data_type = "e"
                        #value = "#VALUE!"
```